# Problem aligning two elements inside a button on bootstrap

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to stick two texts horizontally inside a button by using Bootstrap 4.
The word "Link" is always pushed to the next line and I want it to be next to "Copy".

I've tried using Float but it pushes "Link" too far to the right.

```
<div className="col-3 w3-button w3-tiny">
  <button
    onClick={() => {
      this.copyReferralLink();
    }}
    className="btn btn-block btn-primary"
  >
    {this.props.t("Copy")}
    <span className="d-none d-sm-block btn-primary float-right">
      {this.props.t("link")}
    </span>
  </button>
</div>
```

This is what I have so far, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd use `d-sm-inine-block` instead of `d-sm-block` class.

Additionally you might want to wrap `this.props.t("Copy")` into a `span` of its own.